# Dash instead of the date of django-table

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-tables2

In my application I am using django-tables. But in the template instead of the date from and date to - there are dashes.

My code in the view:

```
class MyTable(BaseTable):
    user = tables.Column(
        order_by=('user__last_name', 'user__first_name'),
        accessor='user.get_full_name',
        verbose_name=_('Worker')
    )

    date_from = tables.DateTimeColumn()
    date_to = tables.DateTimeColumn()

    class Meta(BaseTable.Meta):
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('user', 'country', 'date_from', 'date_to')
```

Comment: Can you post you models? Have you tried explicitly making the date using the model datetime field reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that column reference errors fail silently in django-tables2, and the dashes in the column (I'm assuming every field in the column is as a dash) is the way you know.

Posting your model would make it more helpful, but if you maybe want to set some other tables.Column stuff in your table definition, you could try changing:

```
date_from = tables.DateTimeColumn()
date_to = tables.DateTimeColumn()
```

to

```
date_from = tables.DateColumn()
date_to = tables.DateColumn()
```

If that doesn't work, or if you don't need to set any attribute in your table definition (and assuming that MyModel defines `date_from` and `date_to`) try just removing the two lines above so that you have

```
class MyTable(BaseTable):
    user = tables.Column(
        order_by=('user__last_name', 'user__first_name'),
        accessor='user.get_full_name',
        verbose_name=_('Worker')
    )

    class Meta(BaseTable.Meta):
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('user', 'country', 'date_from', 'date_to')
```